# Valid way of plotting Out-of-Bag error combined randomForest model

Tags: r, random-forest

Due to RAM limitations, I had to split up my 68 tree model into 4 models of 17 trees each. I used the `combine()` function to combine the 4 models into one. When I ran `plot.randomForest()` on the model, I got the error `Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :   'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`.

Digging into the randomForest object, I found that the `err.rate` attribute is missing. And found it actually says so in the `combine()` help function:

> The confusion, err.rate, mse and rsq components (as well as the corresponding components in the test compnent, if exist) of the combined object will be NULL.

I could fairly easily make a plot of Out-of-Bag error with a different line per model. But is there a **valid** way to still plot the `err.rate` of the different models so that the x-axis still represents the number of trees? I could make one long vector that is ordered on `err.rate`, but I am not sure whether this would be a valid representation.

I can't offer a reproducible sample because the data is way too large to share.

Edit: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/combining-randomforests-in-r-why-are-the-err-rate-mse-and-rsq-components-null?rq=1) answered the question!